# Retrieving product attributes data and values using WooCommerce API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I'm trying to retrieve the product attributes of a WooCommerce product using this:

```
$m = get_post_meta($pid, '_product_attributes', false);
```

Where $pid is the ID of my product.

It partially works, but it doesn't return the value of the attributes. I have size and color set on the wp-admin...

```
[pa_size] => Array
    (
        [name] => pa_size
        [value] =>
        [position] => 0
        [is_visible] => 1
        [is_variation] => 1
        [is_taxonomy] => 1
    )

[pa_color] => Array
    (
        [name] => pa_color
        [value] =>
        [position] => 1
        [is_visible] => 1
        [is_variation] => 1
        [is_taxonomy] => 1
    )
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3, you should better use `WC_Product` method `get_attributes()` as follow:

```
$product    = wc_get_product( $pid ); // get an instance of the WC_Product Object
$attributes = $product->get_attributes(); // Get an array of WC_Product_Attribute Objects

// Loop through product WC_Product_Attribute objects
foreach ( $attributes as $name => $values ) {
    $label_name       = wc_attribute_label($values->get_name()); // Get product attribute label name

    $data             = $values->get_data(); // Unprotect attribute data in an array

    $is_for_variation = $data['is_variation']; // Is it used for variation
    $is_visible       = $data['is_visible']; // Is it visible on product page
    $is_taxonomy      = $data['is_taxonomy']; // Is it a custom attribute or a taxonomy attribute


    $option_values    = array(); // Initializing

    // For taxonomy product attribute values
    if( $is_taxonomy ) {
        $terms = $values->get_terms(); // Get attribute WP_Terms

        // Loop through attribute WP_Term
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $term_name     = $term->name; // get the term name
            $option_values[] = $term_name;
        }
    }
    // For "custom" product attributes values
    else {
        // Loop through attribute option values
        foreach ( $values->get_options() as $term_name ) {
            $option_values[] = $term_name;
        }
    }

    // Output for testing
    echo '<strong>' . $label_name . '</strong>:
    <ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $option_values) . '</li><br>';
}
```

Tested and works.